# React development in Visual Studio Code : refactor a component to its own file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, Is there a way to refactor a React component to its own file? I frequently write components  within another component's file and I later move them to their own file. A refactor would be great, to create a file with the component's name, and copy all necessary imports.